# QListView max number of items in view

Tags: qt, qt5, qlistview

I need to calculate max number of items in current view of QListView.
I wrote code like this:

```
void MyListView::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    QListView::resizeEvent(event);

    QFontMetrics fm (this->font());
    int fontHeight = fm.lineSpacing();

    QRect cr = contentsRect();
    int windowHeight = cr.bottom() - cr.top();

    int maxItemsCount = windowHeight / fontHeight;
    qDebug()<<"max items in view: "<< maxItemsCount;

}
```

but calculated max number of items is is incorrect. 
E.g. in case of my window height and font height I get 32 max items in view when in fact current view has 28 items. Perhaps someone can suggest something, how to calculate it properly?

Comment: Spacing/padding between items probably affects this, no? I don't know how well you can solve this (without direct support from the toolkit) but it sounds like it might need theme introspection and therefore be tricky, at best.

Comment: yes but I've checked spacing() and it's 0 not sure how to get padding value

Comment: Just an idea... You may try something else: [QListView::indexAt()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#indexAt) (inherited from `QAbstractView`). Applying it to top-left-corner and bottom-left-corner, you should get two indices, from which you can obtain the difference. (There are probably some edge cases you should care of, e.g. if the current view isn't filled completely.)

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to use [**QListView::indexAt()**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#indexAt) (inherited from `QAbstractView`) to obtain the row index for

1. the top-left corner
2. the bottom-left corner

of the list view viewport and determining the number of visible items by difference of them.

To check this out, I made an MCVE `testQListViewNumVisibleItems.cc`:

```
// Qt header:
#include <QtWidgets>

class ListWidget: public QListWidget {

  public:
    ListWidget(QWidget *pQParent = nullptr): QListWidget(pQParent) { }
    virtual ~ListWidget() = default;
    ListWidget(const ListWidget&) = delete;
    ListWidget& operator=(const ListWidget&) = delete;

    int getNumVisibleItems() const
    {
      const QSize size = viewport()->size();
      const QModelIndex qMIdx0 = indexAt(QPoint(0, 0));
      const QModelIndex qMIdx1 = indexAt(QPoint(0, size.height() - 1));
      //qDebug() << "qMIdx0:" << qMIdx0 << "qMIdx1:" << qMIdx1;
      return qMIdx0.isValid()
        ? (qMIdx1.isValid() ? qMIdx1.row() : count()) - qMIdx0.row()
        : 0;
    }
};

const int MaxItems = 20;

// main application
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  ListWidget qLst;
  qLst.resize(200, 200);
  qLst.show();
  // timer to populate list view
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;
  QTimer qTimer;
  qTimer.setInterval(1000ms);
  // install signal handlers
  int n = 0;
  QObject::connect(&qTimer, &QTimer::timeout,
    [&]() {
      qLst.addItem(QString("item %0").arg(++n));
      qDebug() << "Visible items:" << qLst.getNumVisibleItems();
      if (n >= MaxItems) qTimer.stop();
    });
  // runtime loop
  qTimer.start();
  return app.exec();
}
```

and a `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
project(QListViewNumVisibleItems)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0)

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

find_package(Qt5Widgets CONFIG REQUIRED)

include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")

add_executable(testQListViewNumVisibleItems testQListViewNumVisibleItems.cc)

target_link_libraries(testQListViewNumVisibleItems Qt5::Widgets)
```

built and tested in VS2017 on Windows 10:

[image: snapshot of testQListViewNumVisibleItems.exe (animated)]

---

After having implemented what came in my mind, I googled a bit to possibly see other approaches. (I admit I should've done before.)

Thereby I found the following possible duplicate:

[SO: **Simple way to get all visible items in the QListView**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9818410/7478597)

The accepted answer doesn't contain much more than the hint for `indexAt` and a link to a Qt-FAQ article:

> [**How can i get hold of all of the visible items in my QListView?**](https://wiki.qt.io/Technical_FAQ#How_can_i_get_hold_of_all_of_the_visible_items_in_my_QListView.3F)
>
> In order to get hold of the visible items in a QListView http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html, then you can iterate over them using indexAt() http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#indexAt. You can get hold of the first visible item using indexAt(QPoint(0, 0)), then in order to get the index at the next position then use visualRect() http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#visualRect to find out what your next call to itemAt() should be. This position would be:
>
> ```
> visualRect.y() + visualRect.height() + 1 effectively.
> ```
>
> See the following example for an illustration:
>
> ```
> #include <QtGui>
> QList <QModelIndex>myList;
>
> class ListView : public QListView
> {
>   Q_OBJECT
> public:
>   ListView()
>   {
>     QStringListModel *myModel = new QStringListModel(this);
>     QStringList list;
>     list << "a" << "b" <<"c" <<"d" <<"e" <<"f" <<"g" <<"h" <<"i" <<"j" <<"k";
>     myModel->setStringList(list);
>     setModel(myModel);
>     QTimer::singleShot(3000, this, SLOT(test1()));
>   }
>   public slots:
>     void test1()
>     {
>
>       QModelIndex firstIndex = indexAt(QPoint(0, 0));
>       if (firstIndex.isValid()) {
>         myList << firstIndex;
>       } while (viewport()->rect().contains(QPoint(0, visualRect(firstIndex).y() + visualRect(firstIndex).height() + 1 ))) {
>         firstIndex = indexAt(QPoint(0, visualRect(firstIndex).y() + visualRect(firstIndex).height() + 1 ));
>         myList << firstIndex;
>       }
>       qDebug() << myList.count() << "are visible";
>     }
> };
>
> #include "main.moc"
>
> int main(int argc, char** argv)
> {
>   QApplication app(argc, argv);
>   ListView window;
>   window.resize(100, 50);
>   window.show();
>   return app.exec();
>
> }
> ```

Comment: thanks but I need to know max number of items in the view before loading any items. it should be base on widget resizeEvent